# How to know if numbers in string are ordered in Java

Tags: java, string

I'm wondering how could I implement a boolean method in java that tells me whether the numbers in a string are ordered ascendantly or not.

For example, lets say I have this string.

```
ZALAME 2 3
PECASH 1 3 6
PATEAN 3 4
RAMION 3 6
```

I need to implement some method like:

```
public boolean areOrdered(String theText){
//Lets say I do separate each line of the String into a String array.
String[] lines = theText.split(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
//Now I could do some FOR loop in order to check each individual string.
for(int i = 0; i<lines.length; i++){
//Here is where I check the numbers, taking appart the letters. How could I do it?
if (condition that only applies if numbers are not ordered) return false;
}
return true;
}
```

The outpust should be:

```
    If I check this one:
    ZALAME 2 3
    PECASH 1 3 6
    PATEAN 3 4
    RAMION 3 6
It would return **true** BUT if I check this one:
    ZALAME 3 2
    PECASH 1 3 6
    PATEAN 3 4
    RAMION 3 6
It would return **false**
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I feel some flame inside of you. I just asked in order to see if someone has a better solution than I do. I'm not dropping my homework on anyone, if you want to help me, do it, if not, just don't stop here. Your comment is useless.

Comment: Well, that happens here. The point is that your posting very much sounds like you dropped your complete assignment here. It is hard to believe that you understand how to split text; iterate over lines, but then fail to iterate over a string to retrieve the numbers within the string in order to check if they are ordered or not. Especially when you are argue that "using Collection classes" is a problem for you. Such restrictions are typical for homework assignments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should: 1) tokenize input string, 2) collect numbers from tokens, 3) compare sorted number list to initial

```
String input = "PECASH 1 3 6";
boolean acsending = isAcsending(input); 

...

public static isAcsending(String input) {

   String[] splitted = input.split("\\s+");  // tokenize string
   List<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<>(); 
   for (String s : splitted) {  
     try {
         ints.add(Integer.parseInt(s));         // try to parse each token 
     } catch (RuntimeException ignored) { }
   }
   List<Integer> sorted = new ArrayList<>(ints);
   Collections.sort(sorted);
   return ints.equals(sorted);               // compare
}
```

I know that this can be done in O(n) rather than O(nlogn) and use sort operation to make code cleaner.

Comment: That's a very good solution but it involves the Collections library. Let's wait if someone else has another idea, if not, I will mark your answer.
Thanks!

Comment: @RzvGG instead of adding int values into collection, you can use array, and iterate over it checking `a[i] <= a[i+1]`